# Amazon Advertisng api settup invalid scope error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-advertising-api

I have client id and access token . After sending this api request .

```
https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa?client_id=YOUR_LWA_CLIENT_ID&scope=cpc_advertising:campaign_management&response_type=code&redirect_uri=YOUR_RETURN_URL
```

It return this error

> -?error_description=An+unknown+scope+was+requested&error=invalid_scope

Answer (score 0):

I would contact the Advertising team with this, but this usually means that the client-id you're using does not have the correct permissions to access data for that scope. Did you apply for Advertising API access with that client-id? Do you have multiple client-ids that you may have mixed up?

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the request. Must be profile, profile:user_id, postal_code, or some combination, separated by spaces (e.g. profile%20postal_code). For more information, see [Customer Profile](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/customer-profile.html).

Here is the [Docs](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/authorization-code-grant.html)